# How do I implement these entity relationships in a database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

We Have these relationships:

```
Smith <=> Williams 
Williams <=> Thomas
Smith <=> Thomas
Smith <=> Jones
```

That means Smith friend of Williams and vice-versa.
If you want to find friends of each person like Williams, need search two sides.
I apply this relationship in database like this:

```
id   name1     name2
1    Smith     Williams
2    Williams  Thomas
3    Smith     Thomas
4    Smith     Jones
```

Or like this:

```
id   name1     name2
1    Smith     Williams
2    Williams  Smith
3    Williams  Thomas
4    Thomas    Williams
5    Smith     Thomas
6    Thomas    Smith
7    Smith     Jones
8    Jones     Smith
```

Is there any better solution?

Comment: you should have one table with id-name and another one that represent the relationship, using their ids.

Comment: It's called Many-To-Many relationship. Google it

Comment: I'd go with the first solution

Comment: I would go with @Sebastianb approach. Called as many to many relationship. Put all the names in a table and relate them using a second table in which you would have two columns maintaining the user ID`s of 1st user and his friend.

Comment: @AmithRajShetty can you explain more about many-to-many for this relationship?

Comment: click [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) to get a gist.

Comment: This seems like it would be much more suited to a graph database

Answer (score 1):

You only needs two tables:

Table `[People]` with id and name
and table `[Relationship]` with two ids, each a FK to People id.

Note you can consider the relation bidirectional or unidirectional, that dependeds on your implementation really. Of course if your relation is unidirectional you will need to insert Smith <=> Jones and Jones <=> Smith in yout relationship table.

It's a [Many-to-Many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) relationship but note instead of relation is between two different tables (unlike authors and books in the Wikipedia example) you are doing the relation between two different entities in the same table.

**Bonus:** If you do need to categorize the kind of relationship between two people you can do that with a third table `[RelationshipType]` just with a description and a id and add this id to the Relationship table.